# How to convert Hex char into bytes like \x90\x90?

Tags: c, string, hex, byte

I am searching a way to convert hex char to bytes like `\x90\x0d\x41` and when I use `printf()`, binary data are printed?

```
char *hex = "909090904241";
```

when I need to get `\x90\x90\x90\x90\x42\x42` and when I print I get binary data.

Comment: loop through 2 characters at a time and call [`strtoul`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoul/) with a base of 16

Comment: "when I need to get '\x90\x90\x90\x90\x42\x42' and wheni print i get binary Data" needs to be more specific. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show the expected output, and the actual output as text *in the question*.

Comment: Why expect `x42\x42` from `"4241"`?

Comment: @chux my bad sorry .. i wanted \x42\x41

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Loop through the string and append to a new string a piece with `\x` added infront like this:

```
const char *hex = "909090904241";
char* result = malloc((strlen(hex) * 2 + 1)* sizeof(char));
result[0] = 0;
char piece[] = "\\x00";
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(hex); i+=2) {
  piece[2] = hex[i];
  piece[3] = hex[i+1];
  strcat(result, piece);
}
```

Comment: Correct, I forgot about that. Added.

Comment: With `n=strlen(hex)`, `strcat(result, piece);` inside the loop makes for an O(n*n) solution.  This can be quite slow for a long string.  O(n) can readily be had.

Answer (score 2):

```
int hex_to_bytes(const char* hex, uint8_t** buf_ptr, size_t** len_ptr) {
   size_t len = strlen(hex);
   if (len % 2)
      goto error1;

   len /= 2;
   char* buf = malloc(len);
   char hex_byte[3];
   hex_byte[2] = 0;
   for (size_t i=len; i--; ) {
      hex_byte[0] = *(hex++);
      hex_byte[1] = *(hex++);
      char* end_ptr;
      buf[i] = strtoul(hex_byte, &end_ptr, 16);
      if (end_ptr != hex_byte+2)
         goto error2;
   }

   *buf_ptr = buf;
   *len_ptr = len;
   return 1;

error2:
   free(buf);
error1:
   *buf_ptr = NULL;
   *len_ptr = 0;
   return 0;
}


uint8_t* buf;
size_t len;
if (!hex_to_bytes(hex, &buf, &len)) {
   ... handle error ...
}

... Use buf and len ...
free(buf);
```

Notes that `buf` isn't nul-terminated. I didn't see the point of making it nul-terminated string when the input could be `"000000"`.

Comment: @yano, Yeah, just noticed and fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For each character in the string, first convert it to a number by subtracting its ASCII by either the character `'0'` or `'A'`.  Then assign each value into the target array, shifting as necessary.

The below assumes ASCII, and that the input string contains only characters in the range 0-9 and A-F.

```
char *str="909090904241";
unsigned char a[strlen(str)/2+1] = {0};
int i;

for (i=0;i<strlen(str);i++) {
    unsigned char num = (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9') ? str[i] - '0' : str[i] - 'A' + 10;
    a[i/2] |= num << (4 * (1 - (i % 2)));   // shift even index bits by 4, odd index by 0
}
for (i=0;i<strlen(str)/2+1;i++) {
    printf("%02x ", a[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Output:

```
90 90 90 90 42 41
```

Answer (score 0):

so basically I have a variable which contains hex bytes and when I print them I obtain binary representation

```
#include<stdio.h>

char *hex_bytes = "\x90\x90\x90\x41";

int main () {
    printf(hex_bytes);
    return 0 ;
```

}

I wanna do the same with  hex chars like that

```
char *hex = "9090904241";
```

Thank you , HM