# Sha256 in C program, char to byte conversion

Tags: c, hash, openssl, byte, sha256

I have a c function that returns an unsigned char array

```
unsigned char var[]="600ffe422b4e00731a59557a5cca46cc183944191006324a447bdb2d98d4b408";
```

the char array contains a hex string. I want to hash that char array using sha256 function

```
unsigned char *d = SHA256(var, strlen(var),0);
```

buy it gives me a wrong output unless an until I manually hardcode it in this way

```
unsigned char var[] = {0x60,0x0f,0xfe,0x42,0x2b,0x4e,0x00,0x73,0x1a,0x59,0x55,0x7a,0x5c,0xca,0x46,0xcc,0x18,0x39,0x44,0x19,0x10,0x06,0x32,0x4a,0x44,0x7b,0xdb,0x2d,0x98,0xd4,0xb4,0x08};
```

What I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
 #include <openssl/ripemd.h>

int main (void) {

 unsigned char var[] = {0x60,0x0f,0xfe,0x42,0x2b,0x4e,0x00,0x73,0x1a,0x59,0x55,0x7a,0x5c,0xca,0x46,0xcc,0x18,0x39,0x44,0x19,0x10,0x06,0x32,0x4a,0x44,0x7b,0xdb,0x2d,0x98,0xd4,0xb4,0x08}
unsigned char *d = SHA256(var, strlen(var), 0);

int i;
for (i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    printf("%02x", d[i]);
putchar('\n');
```

how can I programmatically convert this

```
unsigned char var[]="600ffe422b4e00731a59557a5cca46cc183944191006324a447bdb2d98d4b408";
```

to this

```
unsigned char var[]{0x60,0x0f,0xfe,0x42,0x2b,0x4e,0x00,0x73,0x1a,0x59,0x55,0x7a,0x5c,0xca,0x46,0xcc,0x18,0x39,0x44,0x19,0x10,0x06,0x32,0x4a,0x44,0x7b,0xdb,0x2d,0x98,0xd4,0xb4,0x08}
```

in c language and then pass it to sha256 function

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to convert Hex char into bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508787/how-to-convert-hex-char-into-bytes-like-x90-x90)

Comment: @Brian I agree, though I have to say that this question is written far better than that one.

Comment: `strlen` expects a null terminated string. Since your `var` array contains no null byte, it will read past the end of the array, resulting in _undefined behavior_. If `var` happened to contain null bytes, those might be part of the data, but `strlen` would only count up to just before the first null byte.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". -- What have you tried so far to convert the textual representation (the hex *string*) into the byte array? -- Please show some effort, and if you experience problems, come back and [edit] your question.